# Which filters or actions involve with index page for plugin?

Tags: plugins, filters, wp-admin, actions

I decide to manipulate index page or all pages except admin page with plugin but I don't know which filters or actions control index page. for example if I want write plugin that shows a link to admin page which filter or action responsible for it?

Comment: What does "manipulate index page"? Alter the query? Alter the template that loads? Insert content? What?

Comment: change the content like insert a link to index page for example in top of page, but this task must be done with plugin, which filter or action can i use to this propose? you know there is a lot of filter and action it's hard to find appropriate filter or action fot this issue.

Answer (score 0):

There are only a few reliable filters for front end content, `the_content` being the only one that seems reasonably applicable. With that you can insert content in the post body.

There are also actions like `template_redirect` and `template_include` but I doubt those execute where you want them to and using them could be tricky anyway.

There is also a [`loop_start`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.2/wp-includes/query.php#L2851) action that executes, as the name suggests, when the Loop starts. `echo`ing content from that would be very prone to error though.

I don't honestly know it there is a hook that will work for you.

Comment: OK i test them and tell you the result